# Ionic Button animation issue

Tags: css, ionic-framework, css-animations

Im used `Ionic-3` for my university project ,I want to know how to do button animation example when I Click the button i want to show some animation(look at my attached image-02) Actually I don't know  how to do that on ionic,  look at my attached image (I don't want to like as image-02 , I want to know how to make just simple animate for button, some starts, or moves and fly or anything   )

**Image-01**

[image: Image -01 normal button]

**Image-02** (I want to know how to do that like as)

[image: Image-02]

**my code**

```
<div class="login-box">
 <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="signup-col">
        <button ion-button class="submit-btn" full  [navPush]="addnewPage">Add New</button>

      </ion-col>


    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="signup-col">
        <button ion-button class="submit-btn" full   [navPush]="storePage" > Add Store</button>

      </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem

1. Need to install this package `npm install --save css-animator`
2. import a link to the hosted file inside our **src/index.html** somewhere inside the head area: [animate.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css)
3. import  **src/app/app.module.ts** and load the **AnimationService** and **AnimatesDirective:**

**like this**

```
 `import { AnimationService, AnimatesDirective } from 'css-animator';
     declarations: [
        ...
        AnimatesDirective
     ]
     providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        AnimationService
      ]`
```

4. **src/pages/home/home.ts** and insert this button which is inside a div block that has our animations directive:

**like this** (for flipInX)

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { AnimationService, AnimationBuilder } from 'css-animator';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('myElement') myElem;
  private animator: AnimationBuilder;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, animationService: AnimationService) {
    this.animator = animationService.builder();
  }

  animateElem() {
    this.animator.setType('flipInX').show(this.myElem.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

5.inside a `div` block that has our animations directive:

Simple animation directiveXHTML

`<ion-content padding>
  <div animates #animation="animates" text-center>
    <button ion-button (click)="animation.start({type: 'rubberBand', duration: '1000'})">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>`

its work for me

learn more about it  [How to Add Animations To Your Ionic App](https://devdactic.com/animations-ionic-app/)